# linux script find files older than x days and delete

Tags: linux, bash, file

Hello i have problem with script, I would like to delete files older than 7 days, but I did something wrong:) and  does not work. thank you in advance for your help

```
 #!/bin/bash

# sudo apt-get install pydf
#pydf

# source 
DST="/mnt/share/backup"

#find TIF
FINDFILE=*.TIF


if ! [ -f "$DST/$FINDFILE" ]; then
    echo "no file in: $DST"
    find $DST -type f -mtime +7 -name '*.TIF'
    if ! [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
       echo "ERROR  $DST/"
       exit 200
    fi
else    
    echo "file exist"
    echo "older than 7 days wiil deleted "

    find $DST -type f -mtime +7 -name '*.TIF' -execdir rm -- {} \;
    if ! [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
       echo "ERROR : $DST"
       exit 200
    fi
fi
```

if file dosent exist then `find $DST -type f -mtime +7 -name '*.TIF'` if exist `find $DST -type f -mtime +7 -name '*.TIF' -execdir rm -- {} \;`

**OUTPUT terminal**

```
root@fmx2-virtual-machine:/home/fm-x2# ./find.sh
no file in: /mnt/share/backup
/mnt/share/backup/P1010007.TIF
/mnt/share/backup/P1010004.TIF
/mnt/share/backup/P1010003.TIF
/mnt/share/backup/P1010009.TIF
/mnt/share/backup/P1010008.TIF
/mnt/share/backup/P1010005.TIF
/mnt/share/backup/P1010006.TIF

root@fmx2-virtual-machine:/mnt/share/backup# ls -lh
razem 224M
-rw-r--r-- 1 fm-x2 fm-x2 82M sty 13 09:37 2016-01-13.backup.tar.bz2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 fm-x2 fm-x2 21M gru 31  2004 P1010003.TIF
-rwxr-xr-x 1 fm-x2 fm-x2 21M gru 31  2004 P1010004.TIF
-rwxr-xr-x 1 fm-x2 fm-x2 21M gru 31  2004 P1010005.TIF
-rwxr-xr-x 1 fm-x2 fm-x2 21M gru 31  2004 P1010006.TIF
-rwxr-xr-x 1 fm-x2 fm-x2 21M gru 31  2004 P1010007.TIF
-rwxr-xr-x 1 fm-x2 fm-x2 21M gru 31  2004 P1010008.TIF
-rwxr-xr-x 1 fm-x2 fm-x2 21M gru 31  2004 P1010009.TIF
root@fmx2-virtual-machine:/mnt/share/backup#
```

at beginning is error `if ! [ -f "$DST/$FINDFILE" ]; then` if no tiff exit.

***problem solved***

13 line  `if ! [ "$DST/$FINDFILE" ]; then`

```
root@fmx2-virtual-machine:/home/fm-x2# ./find.sh
file exist
older than 7 days wiil deleted 

root@fmx2-virtual-machine:/mnt/share/backup# ls -l
razem 83536
-rw-r--r-- 1 fm-x2 fm-x2 85538248 sty 13 09:37 2016-01-13.backup.tar.bz2
```

Comment: `does not work`, care to expand on this ?

Comment: yes does not work output terminal: `no file in: /mnt/share/backup
/mnt/share/backup/P1010007.TIF
/mnt/share/backup/P1010004.TIF` and does not delete files

Comment: Please post the entire output in your question.

Comment: `-f` accepts a single file as an argument, also the `*` won't expand as you have it in quotes. so you are searching for a file called `*.TIFF` which evidently does not exist.

Comment: yes  it was f `-f` without  f work `if ! [ "$DST/$FINDFILE" ]; then`. Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

You can perform this task using find and piping:

```
find path/to/directory -time +7 | xargs rm
```